# Objective-C: Enable/Disable File Reading (chmod a-r)

Tags: objective-c, file-permissions, chmod

Using Objective-C, how can I give/take the permissions for all user to read a file?

I need something that has the same effects as `chmod a-r` and `chmod a+r`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you also familiar with the `chmod 755 file` method of changing permissions? using octal numbers?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 

//Prefixing zero is octal.
int readPermission = 04;
int writePermission = 02;
int executePermission = 01;

//End multiplication is to shift digits left.
int owner = (readPermission | writePermission | executePermission) * (8 * 8);   //7
int group = (readPermission)                                       * (8);       //4 
int other = (executePermission);                                                //1

int permissions = owner + group + other;  //0741

[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:permissions] forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions]; 

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:dict ofItemAtPath:[file path] error:&error];
```

Comment: In case it wasn't clear to anyone, this sets the permissions to 777 — i.e. anybody can do anything.

Comment: Please note I havent tested this, and the octal stuff should be checked a bit more before use.

Comment: @Chuck's comment was right, but since an edit, the permissions are now 741

Comment: @JamesWebster the first version of your code seems to work fine :) thank you!

Comment: Oh good =]. I hadn't tested it. I've edited it a bit to make the permissions a bit more obvious

Comment: `readPermission & writePermission & executePermission` == 0 because it's AND-ing and none of the bits are in common. Anyway, don't compute permission masks using home-grown constants and math. Use `#include <sys/stat.h>` and then things like `S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXOTH`.

Comment: Good spot. I didn't know such a library existed, though those constants aren't pretty to read.

Comment: @JamesWebster: They may not be pretty to read, but they are defined by POSIX and various other standards, which means they're heavily documented, recognizable to other programmers, never going to change, and portable to other platforms.

Comment: @JamesWebster: Also, if you want to shift left, why not use the left shift operator instead of using multiplication and then adding a comment that explains it?

Comment: Also, chmod a-r and a+r change the read bits while leaving the other bits alone, while this code replaces all of the bits.

Comment: Because I'm under the impression the << operator is for binary numbers. I suppose I could have done << 6 and << 3 but with a base 8 system, a shift my multiplying by 8 seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: You seem to be picking fault where there is no need. The code I wrote is capable of changing read permissions. How you use it determines if it's capable of a-r and a+r. Wrap it in a function to just change read bits and your done. I gave the OP the tools they needed, not just an answer on a plate.

Answer (score 3):

To do this in Objective C:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDict *attribs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[file path] error:&error];
int permissions = [[attribs objectForKey:@"NSFilePosixPermissions"] intValue];
permissions |= (S_IRSUR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
NSDict *newattribs = [NSDict dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:permissions]
                                           forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions];
[fm setAttributes:dict ofItemAtPath:[file path] error:&error];
```

Or, just get a POSIX path (with -[NSFileManager fileSystemRepresentationForPath]) and do it in C, using the chmod function—which is what the chmod command-line tool uses, and is portable to any POSIX platform.